# Wrong result of integral $\int_{1}^3{\ln(x+1) \cdot \sin(x)}dx$ on calculator EL-W506X

Tags: definite-integrals, calculator

I just solved on Khan Academy the following problem, which gives me on my calculator EL-W506X the wrong answer. Why is that?

$$\int_{1}^3{\ln(x+1)\cdot \sin(x) dx} = 1.57079$$ (says on Wolfram Alpha), but on my EL-W506X gives the value of $0.079306699$.

Comment: have you checked whether your calculator is on radian mode?

Because wolfram will produce the result of $\sin(3)$ for the units of radians

Comment: Have you double (triple) checked your input?

Comment: Oh, cool, just radian mode.... Thanks for that.

Comment: @Jneven Please post as an answer for the OP to accept so the question doesn't stay on the unanswered queue.

Comment: The right result is this here $$-1/2\,{{\rm e}^{-i}}{\it Ei} \left( 1,-4\,i \right) +1/2\,{{\rm e}^{-i
}}{\it Ei} \left( 1,-2\,i \right) +1/2\,{{\rm e}^{i}}{\it Ei} \left( 1
,2\,i \right) -1/2\,{{\rm e}^{i}}{\it Ei} \left( 1,4\,i \right) +\ln 
 \left( 2 \right)  \left( \cos \left( 1 \right) -2\,\cos \left( 3
 \right)  \right) 
$$

Answer (score 1):

have you checked whether your calculator is on radian mode? Because wolfram will produce the result of $sin(3)$ for the units of radians, and your calculator might be using different units.